# How do you prepare a model to encode properly

Tags: json, swift, object, encode, codable

```
API Objects
Types of JSON objects served by Gutendex are given below.

Book
{
  "id": <number of Project Gutenberg ID>,
  "title": <string>,
  "subjects": <array of strings>,
  "authors": <array of Persons>,
  "translators": <array of Persons>,
  "bookshelves": <array of strings>,
  "languages": <array of strings>,
  "copyright": <boolean or null>,
  "media_type": <string>,
  "formats": <Format>,
  "download_count": <number>
}
Format
{
  <string of MIME-type>: <string of URL>,
  ...
}
Person
{
  "birth_year": <number or null>,
  "death_year": <number or null>,
  "name": <string>
}
```

There is an API service that returns the types above. I managed to create objects for Book and person on swift but I don't know how to implement a codable struct for "Format"

Comment: `.decode([String:String].self, from: data)` or `.decode([String:URL].self, from: data)`

Comment: Do you care only for certain mime-type, or do you want them all? Depending on the answer, either decode them as `Dict`, or use a custom Codable struct. If your issue is about the slash in the mime-type, use custom CodingKeys

Comment: copy and paste the "real" json data into https://app.quicktype.io/ and all your code structs will be generated for you. If you want to really do it by hand, keep doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Codable is a protocol you can conform your struct or class to that handles this for you. The JSON key defaults to the field name, however, you can override it with a coding key. This is a pretty close representation of what you're looking for, however, the `formats` field was a little ambiguous.

```swift
struct Book: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let subjects: [String]
    let authors: [Person]
    let translators: [Person]
    let bookshelves: [String]
    let languages: [String]
    let copyright: Bool?
    let mediaType: String
    let numberOfDownloads: Int
    let formats: [String : String] // This wasn't clear in your example

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, subjects, authors, translators, bookshelves,
            languages, copyright, formats // No need to override the key
        case mediaType = "media_type"
        case numberOfDownloads = "download_count"
}

struct Person: Codable {
    let birthYear: Int?
    let deathYear: Int?
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name // No need to override the key
        case birthYear = "birth_year"
        case deathYear = "death_year"
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, but as I said, I did almost exactly what you wrote, the only missing part was the "format" part for me.

Comment: It may be a dictionary [string:string]